# Java SimpleDate formats and parse, dose not generate a unique value?

Tags: java, date, serialization

I want to serial and deserial date as follow:

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

// Data is
Date date = new Date();

// Serial
String sdate = formater.format(date);

// Deserial
Date newDate = formater.parse(sdate);

// Check
assertEquals(newDate, date);
```

How ever, the result (newDate) is not equal to the original date?! Is there any wrong?

Comment: I cannot check currently, but my instinct is: the date has milliseconds, the newDate does not!

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated along with `Date`, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The modern classes like `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` also lend themselves much better to serialization since they can parse back the result of their `toString` without any explicit formatter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A date with the precision of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` does not have sub-second information. You're losing precision.

You can verify by checking the timestamp:

```
date.getTime() - newDate.getTime()
```

The difference will tell you the number of milliseconds you're losing in the process.

This may work accidentally, when `date.getTime()` is a multiple of 1000.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation that Ernest Kiwele gives in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896303/5772882) is correct. Here’s a solution; what to do about it.

```
    Instant inst = Instant.now();

    // Serialize
    String sInst = inst.toString();

    // Deserialize
    Instant newInst = Instant.parse(sInst);

    // Check
    assertEquals(inst, newInst);
```

This test passes. No need for an explicit formatter. `Instant.toString` produces ISO 8601 format (`2018-04-18T15:08:58.314727Z`), and its `parse` method parses the same format back.

You can do the same with a `ZonedDateTime` and the other date-time classes of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

Not only for this reason do I recommend you skip the `Date` class that you used in the question. That class is long outdated, and the modern API is generally so much nicer to work with.

If you did get a `Date` from a legacy API that you cannot change and need to give a `Date` back after serialization and deserialization, serializing as `Instant` is still a convenient option:

```
    Date date = new Date();

    // Serialize
    String sInst = date.toInstant().toString();

    // Deserialize
    Instant newInst = Instant.parse(sInst);
    Date newDate = Date.from(newInst);

    // Check
    assertEquals(date, newDate);
```

One potential advantage is you serialize in ISO 8601 format, the international standard, which makes sure that many tools in many different programming languages could easily deserialize your string if the need should arise.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)